# accessing 'sibling' of array

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

This has been causing me some issues solving:

If I have JSON object coming from a REST endpoint such as this;

```
SomeArray = 
[{"id":"1","genre":"Folk"},
{"id":"2","genre":"punk"},
{"id":"13","genre":"Punk (original)"},
{"id":"14","genre":"Punk (revival)"},
{"id":"25","genre":"Hard Rock"},
{"id":"66","genre":"Heavy Metal"} ..... ]
```

and I know that I want to access the item with an id of 25 for example, and get the value of genre

This for example:

```
 var myID = 25
 var my value = SomeArray[myID].genre
```

looks to the 25th element of the JSON object SomeArray. How can I properly access the sibling of the element with the id = 25 for example and return the genre value?

I tried

```
SomeArray.id[myID].genre but not correct syntax of course.
```

Thanks for any help

This is in an angular controller if there is anything in angular that might assist also you might be aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: You don't really want the 25th item, but the item with id = 25, correct?

Comment: yes , want the item with the id=25, but keep getting the index of the 25th item in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function loop through to find it:

```
function find(someArray, id){
 for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
   if (someArray[i].id == id) {
    return someArray[i]; 
   }
  } 
  return null;
}
```

Then call it..

```
var item = find(someArray, 25);
var genre = item.genre;
```

Comment: worked brilliantly.  Thank you very much I was approaching it the incorrect way.

Comment: No problem. Just handle if 'item' is null too in the case where the id is not found...

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your question correctly but can't you user indexof function like below?

```
    var currentIndex = SomeArray.indexof(myId);
var siblin = SomeArray[currentIndex +1];
```